# Flatlist does not render if have one object in data?

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have some issue with `Flatlist`, I have an array of objects I got them from DB,

and save them to state, now when I log the `this.state.providers` in render() method or in the callback func after setState I got the valid Object like this

`[{username: "Test", key: "53HoDga6aYhHsV5pCi5sx6LGbx42"}]`

but when I passed these object into data prop in `<Flatlist data={this.state.providers} />` the flatlist not rendering!

but when I add the object in the data prop manual like this

`<Flatlist data={[{username: "Test One", key: "53HoDga6aYhHsV5pCi5sx6LGbx42"}]}`

the flatlist work very well,
But I'm sure the code is correct because I added them into other project and work very well!!

### Edit

when I pass tow object into the array the flatlist work!!

so how to handle it if I got one object from DB!

### Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";

class ListChats extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      providers: []
    };
  }
  _chatList = () => {
    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let ref = firebase.database().ref(`Messages/${currentUser}`);
    let providersKeys = [];

    ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(childsnap => {
        console.log(childsnap.key);
        providersKeys.push(childsnap.key);
      });
      let usernames = [];
      providersKeys.forEach(key => {
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("users")
          .child(key)
          .once("value")
          .then(providersShot => {
            let username = providersShot.val().username;
            usernames.push({ username: username, key: key });
          });
      });
      this.setState({ providers: usernames }, () =>
        console.log(this.state.providers)
      );
    });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this._chatList();
  }
  _listEmptyComponent = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>No Chats Found :O</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.providers); // I got [{username: "Test", key: "53HoDga6aYhHsV5pCi5sx6LGbx42"}]
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          key={Math.random() * 1000}
          data={this.state.providers}
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
          ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent()}
          keyExtractor={item => item.key.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            console.log("item", item);
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("ChatDetails", {
                    Key: item.key,
                    providerName: item.username
                  })
                }
              >
                <View style={styles.parent}>
                  <Icon name="ios-contact" size={50} color="#4d8dd6" />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flex: 1,
                      justifyContent: "flex-start",
                      alignItems: "flex-start",
                      marginHorizontal: 25
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: "#000",
                        fontSize: 17
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.username}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <Icon name="ios-chatboxes" size={25} color="#d6d6d6" />
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
          // keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  parent: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingVertical: 25,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "#eee"
  }
});

export default ListChats;
```

Comment: Do you see `console.log("item", item);` ?

Comment: Never!! @Vencovsky

Comment: If you don't get any errors and you never see that console, it means that your list is always empty and it explains why adding the raw data in there works

Comment: So what? When I log the state I can see my data!! @Vencovsky

Comment: How many times do you see `[{username: "Test", key: "53HoDga6aYhHsV5pCi5sx6LGbx42"}]`? because you have two console.logs. One in `_chatList ` and another one in the `render` method. Are both executing?

Comment: Yup `console.log(this.state.providers)` executing in both render and _chatList function! @CarlosJ

Answer (score 0):

You should add `extraData` property to `FlatList`:

```
extraData={this.state}
```

Answer (score 0):

In here your using `usernames.push` method to add the data objects to array, using this method will not indicate the state about a need of a re-render even if the state is updated with a new array.

For this usual coding pattern is using the spread operator

`this.setState({ providers: [...usernames] })`

Answer (score -1):

Use ["extraData"](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata) props of FlatList.

Comment: By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.